# Setting and getting bootstrap radio button inside angular repeat loop

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I am trying to set the default button and get the current selected value.
The example without the repeat loop works.

Here is my plnkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/t9CefA5bhLZs3RASmEUG?p=preview

It is based on this example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/LFj4inY9TLYZs9z7yHCr?p=preview

Thank you!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

So, there were 2 things going on in your plunker.

Firstly the `btn-radio` attribute doesn't need interpolation (`{{}}`) you can (and should) provide an expression directly. So just write `btn-radio="company.id"` instead of `btn-radio="{{company.id}}"`.

Secondly, you must know that the `ng-repeat` directive creates a new scope. This is a very, very common conceptual issue people have with AngularJS so I would encourage you to read https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/The-Nuances-of-Scope-Prototypal-Inheritance

Coming back to you particular problem you can either change you ng-model expression to point to a parent scope (`ng-model="$parent.radioModel"`) or bind to an object property (`ng-model="radioModel.id"`).

Here is a working plunk with the second approach:
http://plnkr.co/edit/uGAxaRlPFK6sD4tRjGXX?p=preview

Comment: Could you please explain the problem in this related question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/18275727/247243

Comment: I never knew that ng-repeat directive creates a new scope. Wow.