# AngularJS UI Bootstrap "btn-radio" directive doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/muCDqEHgJs5f55mWQLFH?p=preview)

Could anyone explain why the first two button groups work, but the third one doesn't?

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button ng-repeat="company in companies" 
          class="btn" 
          ng-model="radioModel.id" 
          btn-radio="company.id">
    {{company.name}}
  </button>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn btn-two" 
          ng-model="radioModel.id"
          btn-radio="2">
    two
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn-two" 
          ng-model="radioModel.id"
          btn-radio="3">
    three
  </button>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button ng-repeat="company in companies" 
          class="btn btn-{{ company.name }}" 
          ng-model="radioModel.id" 
          btn-radio="company.id">
    {{company.name}}
  </button>
</div>
```

```
$scope.companies = [ { id: 2, name: "two"}, {id: 3, name: "three"} ];
$scope.radioModel = { id: 3 };
```

This example uses AngularUI Bootstrap 0.5.0. If I change it to 0.3.0, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `ng-class`. The string interpolation in `class` is funky.

```
ng-class="'btn btn-' + company.name"
```